# Android - Removing app Tittle bar & colored Dialog textbox

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have two questions, so i posted both here, instead of opening two questions separated.

1. I wonder, how can I remove my app Tittle bar?? I don't want to be seen when I start my app on phone
2. Can I color my dialog box like this in example -> To make my dialog tittle bar green and dialog background grey ??

[image]

I made this photo in paint, but this is how I would like to my alert dialog looks like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the title bar beneath the Notification Bar, you can add this single line of code to your `Activity` declaration in the `Mainfest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

This is how I used it:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Splash"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well.... I tried before asking this question with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" , and it didn't work, but this works great :)

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1:
use  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

For Question 2:
[How to change dialog background color programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269706/how-to-change-dialog-background-color-programatically)

Comment: I don't really understand this, but can I make alert dialog like on the uploaded picture in my question ??