# Not able to change alert dialog background

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

Ok I am going crazy over this. I am trying to change alert dialog background color from the default grey to white. I am unable to do so. I am using alert dialog with list

I have extended the parent theme.dialog style and I have tried so many combinations of attributes but I keep getting the white background not only for the list but beyond the dialf boundries (as if the width is fill parent)

When i set the color to transparent then the dialog appears nicely with the list in grey. It seems that the dialog window is transparent and it is fill parent but the list is the one with thegrey colorand thats probably why we dont see the full dialog

How can I fix this??

Comment: Refer This. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269706/how-to-change-dialog-background-color-programatically

Comment: Very useful topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs?rq=1

Comment: Been there before, does not solve the problem of themes

Comment: That was written back in 2010 before api 11 is released. I am using 11 so i can make use of the theme argument

Comment: You can create custom dialog with your own style theme and layouts

Comment: @JaiSoni  by creating custom dialog i am eleminating the use of alert dialog as you cant extendit. I want to make use of existing functionalotu of lists and positive/negative buttons